# Unable to start Next 13 app directory (beta) in production mode

Tags: next.js, async-await, next.js13

Step 1: Automatically create a new Next.js project using the new [beta app directory](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/installation):

```
npx create-next-app@latest --experimental-app
```

**pages/api/hello.ts**

```
// Next.js API route support: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'

type Data = {
  name: string
}

export default function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse<Data>
) {
  res.status(200).json({ name: 'John Doe' })
}
```

This file is identical to the one created automatically created by npx - there are no modifications.

I am trying to build a simple home page, which fetches data from the api which gets data from my database. Either way an await/async will be required. I am following the instructions from [here](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/data-fetching/fetching#asyncawait-in-server-components).

In this example I will demonstrate that even awaiting the supplied hello api can't seem to run in production, and I can't work out why.

**app/page.tsx**

```
async function getHelloAsync() {
  const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/hello', { cache: 'no-store' });

  // The return value is *not* serialized
  // You can return Date, Map, Set, etc.

  // Recommendation: handle errors
  if (!res.ok) {
    // This will activate the closest `error.js` Error Boundary
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch data');
  }

  return res.json();
}

export default async function Page() {

  const hello = await getHelloAsync();

  return (
    <main>
      <h1>Hello: {hello.name}</h1>
    </main>
  )
}
```

To test the hello api works, I confirm that running `pn run dev` and then `curl http://localhost:3000/api/hello` the following successful response is received:

```
{"name":"John Doe"}
```

Next up we exit the dev server and run:

```
pn run build
```

The first headache is that the build will completely fail to build unless one adds { cache: 'no-store' } to the fetch command:

```
const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/hello', { cache: 'no-store' });
```

or adds this to the top of app/page.tsx:

```
export const fetchCache = 'force-no-store';
```

I am actually not sure how one would even build this if you wanted to cache the response or use revalidate instead and provide an initial optimistic response, because without cache: no-store it refuses to build outright. Ideally instead it should just cache the result from /api/hello and not fail. Running the dev server at the same idea as doing the build does allow the build to work, but then as soon as you exit the dev server and run `pn run start` then all the api calls fail anyway. So that is not a good idea.

This leads us to the next problem - why are the api calls not working in production (i.e. when calling `pn run start`).

Step 2:

```
pn run build    
pn run start
```

Confirm that the following still works and yes it does:

```
curl http://localhost:3000/api/hello
```

Result:

```
{"name":"John Doe"}
```

Now we visit http://localhost:3000 in a browser but, surprise! We get the following error:

```
> next start

ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
warn  - You have enabled experimental feature (appDir) in next.config.js.
warn  - Experimental features are not covered by semver, and may cause unexpected or broken application behavior. Use at your own risk.
info  - Thank you for testing `appDir` please leave your feedback at https://nextjs.link/app-feedback

(node:787) ExperimentalWarning: The Fetch API is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
TypeError: fetch failed
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11118:11)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async getHelloAsync (/Users/username/nextjstest/.next/server/app/page.js:229:17)
    at async Page (/Users/username/nextjstest/.next/server/app/page.js:242:19) {
  cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:3000
      at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1300:16)
      at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
    errno: -61,
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    syscall: 'connect',
    address: '::1',
    port: 3000
  }
}
[Error: An error occurred in the Server Components render. The specific message is omitted in production builds to avoid leaking sensitive details. A digest property is included on this error instance which may provide additional details about the nature of the error.] {
  digest: '3567993178'
}
```

Why is it saying that the connection is refused when we know the API is available? I can't get this to run at all. I know this is beta but surely the code should actually run right? How do I make this code work?

Also if anyone knows where where the logs are that I'm supposed to be accessing to see digest '3567993178' please let me know.

Comment: The conclusion I came to is that doing a fetch inside of a server component is just not working right now. It seems to work okay if you get rid of the fetch part. Not that that is a great solution as I'm sure sometimes you'd legitimately need to do a fetch.